# How can I debug haskell monad implementation (or view inner information)

Tags: debugging, haskell, monads

I used to write code using parser combinator library `polyparse`.
I could see intermediate evaulation result with ghci debugger, but it was confined to what my code use. In other words, I couldn't inspect `polyparse`'s `Parser` monad's inner information.

For example I can see only one character which a parser process, but not more. It is difficult to know exactly where the parser is parsing. In other cases, there was a time I misunderstood a `polyparse`'s function and it took a long time to fix it due to opacity of monad evaluation.

I even unpacked `polyparse` package and set breakpoint to `Parser` monad instance, but it wasn't allowed.
Maybe using other good library can be one of alternative, but I want to know there's solution with `polyparse` library, and general one.

Comment: If you are going to make your question about a specific parse it might be helpful to say [which](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/polyparse/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-Poly-Plain.html) [one](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/polyparse/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-HuttonMeijer.html) you [mean](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/polyparse/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-HuttonMeijerWallace.html). These parsers look nastier to debug because their main fields are functions. You'd have to pattern match against the parser to extract the function, then test that it is correct based on input/outputs.

Comment: @Alec: I'm not asking specific parse, and aren't those three same from view of monadic structure? And I'm sorry but I can't understand well the meaning of pattern matching against the parser.

Comment: They are similar (I mean they _are_ all parsers ;)). But yeah, looks like for the package you may have to play with the opaque function, checking that it is right by feeding it inputs and verifying the outputs. Some other parser libraries like [`megaparsec`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-5.1.2/docs/Text-Megaparsec.html#g:6) provide functions to help you debug your parsers.